# dropping duplicate rows from data frame excluding last two columns python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

```
id    city  age  gender  Child  Generation_group   Bodytag   RecordType 
2001   A    2      M      0      ABCD               WW        AW
2002   A    2      M      0      ABCD               AA        WA
2002   A    2      M      0      ABCD               BB        AW
2002   A    2      M      0      ABCD               CC        WA
2004   A    2      M      0      ABCD               DD        AW
2004   A    2      M      0      ABCD               EE        WA
2005   A    2      M      0      ABCD               FF        AW
2005   A    2      M      0      ABCD               QQ        WA
```

I want output like this:

```
id    city  age  gender  Child  Generation_group   Bodytag   RecordType 
2001   A    2      M      0      ABCD               WW        AW
2002   A    2      M      0      ABCD               AA        WA
2002   Null Null   Null   Null   Null               BB        AW
2002   Null Null   Null   Null   Null               CC        WA
2004   A    2      M      0      ABCD               DD        AW
2004   Null Null   Null   Null   Null               EE        WA
2005   A    2      M      0      ABCD               FF        AW
2005   Null Null   Null   Null   Null               QQ        WA
```

I want null values where duplicate ids are there but only in first 5 columns after id columns , I don't want null in last two columns

How do I do it in pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and select columns via `[]`:

```
cols = df.columns
df[cols[1:-2]] = df[cols[1:-2]].mask(df[cols[:-2]].duplicated())
print (df)
     id city  age gender  Child Generation_group Bodytag RecordType
0  2001    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      WW         AW
1  2002    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      AA         WA
2  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      BB         AW
3  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      CC         WA
4  2004    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      DD         AW
5  2004  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      EE         WA
6  2005    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      FF         AW
7  2005  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      QQ         WA
```

Similar solution:

```
cols = df.columns
df[cols[1:-2]] = df[cols[1:-2]].mask(df.duplicated(subset=cols[:-2]))
print (df)
     id city  age gender  Child Generation_group Bodytag RecordType
0  2001    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      WW         AW
1  2002    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      AA         WA
2  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      BB         AW
3  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      CC         WA
4  2004    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      DD         AW
5  2004  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      EE         WA
6  2005    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      FF         AW
7  2005  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      QQ         WA
```

Solution with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:-2] = df.iloc[:, 1:-2].mask(df.iloc[:, :-2].duplicated())
print (df)
     id city  age gender  Child Generation_group Bodytag RecordType
0  2001    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      WW         AW
1  2002    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      AA         WA
2  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      BB         AW
3  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      CC         WA
4  2004    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      DD         AW
5  2004  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      EE         WA
6  2005    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      FF         AW
7  2005  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      QQ         WA
```

EDIT:

If want check for duplicates only first column `id` change `cols[:-2]` to `id` and `df.iloc[:, :-2].duplicated()` to `df.duplicated(subset=['id'])`

Comment: I don't want null at id column

Comment: Sorry, I change it.

Comment: Thank you so much , I have bee tried since long time, finally did it , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to find the duplicate id's, and `df.loc` to select the sub-DataFrame. Notice that [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) can take 2 indexers -- `df.duplicated('id', keep='first')` indexes the rows by boolean selection, and `df.columns[1:6]` selects the columns by label:

```
In [13]: df.loc[df.duplicated('id', keep='first'), df.columns[1:6]] = np.nan

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
     id city  age gender  Child Generation_group Bodytag RecordType
0  2001    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      WW         AW
1  2002    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      AA         WA
2  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      BB         AW
3  2002  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      CC         WA
4  2004    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      DD         AW
5  2004  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      EE         WA
6  2005    A  2.0      M    0.0             ABCD      FF         AW
7  2005  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN      QQ         WA
```